# Velocity controllers and missing P gain

Tags: ros-melodic, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using the `VelocityJointController` from `velocity_controllers` to control a robot loaded in Gazebo simulation. I specify PID gains in a .yaml file. However when I launch the simulation, the error pops out

```
[ERROR] [1546601044.601198350, 0.165000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /robot/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint_rear_left_wheel
```

And no metter what PID gains I set, the robot behaves always the same. The PID gains set in .yaml configuration file has no effect on the simulation.

my transmission:

```
<transmission name="tran_rear_left_wheel">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint_rear_left_wheel">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="motor_rear_left_wheel">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
</transmission>
```

control yaml

```
imow:
  # Publish all joint states -----------------------------------
  joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 50  

  # Velocity Controllers -----------------------------------------
  joint_rear_left_wheel_controller:
    type: velocity_controllers/JointVelocityController
    joint: joint_rear_left_wheel
    pid: {p: 1, i: 1, d: 1}
```

What is happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21620/velocity-controllers-and-missing-p-gain/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2019-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Since Weasfas brought this old question up, I can tell now, that `velocity_controllers` does not use PID for commanding velocity, because the input already is the velocity. It uses PID for controlling positions, however. So if I had controller of type `velocity_controllers/JointPositionController`, I would need to specify PID parameters and the behavior of the robot would depend on those values.

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/61440/croco/) on 2022-05-20**:
not sure how this answers the question. From Control systems perspective, you are right the position part is not needed but how to fix this in Gazebo?